# Integrate custom tokens to tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using [fluentui](https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/theme-colors--page) library and I would integrate colors to tailwind.

```
import { tokens } from "@fluentui/react-components";

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{ts,tsx,html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // Other color definitions...

        // Loop over tokens and return the same object
        ...(() => {
          const tokenColors = {};
          for (const key in tokens) {
            tokenColors[key] = tokens[key];
          }
          return tokenColors;
        })(),
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

In the component:

import "./styles.css";

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-light text-colorNeutralForeground2BrandHover">
        Hello world!
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But it's not working.
I'm looking for the best way to integrate fluent ui tokens

[online demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/yccjqr?migrateFrom=j4qv7q&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00063b6kzvc7w0hm%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00023b6kzoawtlwf%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00043b6ka5v5yhal%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00053b6k5jm42mzz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt1pdkdq00023b6kzoawtlwf%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00023b6kzoawtlwf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt1phzdh00l83b6k14rz3bmo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Ftailwind.config.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1phzdh00l83b6k14rz3bmo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt1pdkdq00053b6k5jm42mzz%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00053b6k5jm42mzz%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt1pmdx8017v3b6k2dun10tf%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdzmg00ca3b6ksvsquc66%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5174%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pihdv00ne3b6ku1tjhwq5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pmdx8017v3b6k2dun10tf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt1pdkdq00043b6ka5v5yhal%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00043b6ka5v5yhal%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00033b6kr18ksful%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkr3000ndkf8bpmc1lol%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt1pdkdq00033b6kr18ksful%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in this [CodeSandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/immutable-cdn-j4qv7q-forked-t2y7vj). Consider providing enough code to reproduce the unexpected behavior.